Need to generate new sequence for duplicates values
input
Name region
abc india
def austrila
ghi india
jkl austrila

Output is
Name region glr_code
abc india 001india
def austrila 001austrila
ghi india 002india
jkl austrila 002austrila

need to get unique for duplicates values any leads to help on this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is classic problem of row_number() over (partition by ...) in SQL. So,
Option 1 - you can do this using any SQL in the source qualifier.
Option 2 - you need to use rank transformation.
In the rank transormation, select the
GroupBy = partition by
rank = order by. Select Top/Bottom in properties for Descending/Ascending order respectively.
number of ranks = maximum number of records you are expecting in each partition. Estimate number of region add 100 to it and set this.
Output -
RankIndex is the row number. Concat this with Region using an expression transformation after the rank.
Your mapping would look like this -
SRC-->SQ --> EXP--> RNK--> EXP--> TGT



You can also use an expression with local variable that will be incremented for same region and reset each time region changes. The data needs to be sorted by region, so the mapping would be as follows:
SRC-->SQ-->SRT-->EXP-->TGT

The expression would need to check the value of previous region, so the following port formulas would be needed in the Expression Transformation:
v_seq = IIF(v_prev_region = region, v_seq + 1, 1)
v_prev_region = region
glr_code = LPAD(v_seq, '0', 3) || region

